# python import function from other file using __init__

Tags: python, import, package, init

I got the following files

```
1 ./run.py
2 ./code/util.py
3 ./code/__init__.py
```

and inside util.py I have

```
def funA():
  print 'Hello World !'
```

and inside ./code/**init**.py I have

```
__all__=['util'];
from util import  *
```

now I open python prompt (actually, ipython) in the current directory then I type

```
from code import *
```

and all I've got is the util module

```
util       module    <module 'code.util' from 'code/util.pyc'>
```

and I have to include the package name in order to use funA(). 
I expected that funA is now in my namespace and I can use it without the package name code.funA . However, this is not the case and I am wondering where the problem is.
I guess I am still somewhat confused to how exactly __ init __.py should be used.

Comment: Why did you specify `__all__ = ['util']` if you wanted other things (like `funA`) to be available?

Comment: What should I do instead ? isn't __all__ =['util'] necessary ?

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding what `__all__` is for.  See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of `__all__` (as [documented](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement)) is to indicate that you want *only* the names listed there to be available via `from mymodule import *`.  By specifying only `'util'`, you are explicitly telling your package to not make anything but `util` available.  If you remove that `__all__`, then everything you import from within `util` will also be available in `code`, and so if you do `from code import *`, then everything from `util` will also be available.

Whether this is a good idea is another matter.  Importing `*` often leads to confusion.

Comment: I don't understand why from util import * is not executed to make the namespace of funA available though.

Comment: @Jing: It is executed.  The problem is that everything it imports into `code` is hidden, because the `__all__` tells `code` not to expose all that stuff.  In other words, your `from util import *` import everything *into `code`*, but `code` blocks it from being imported "out" via `from code import *`.

Comment: blocks ? I thought __all__ tells python to import all those modules in the list whenever from code import * is called. Then it executes whwatever left in __init__.py. Why is from code import * blocks from util import * ?

Comment: @Jing: No, it does just what I said in my answer, and what it says in the documentation.